# Find points A and B from their angle bisectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, plane-geometry

I need to find points $A$ and $B$ in $ℝ^2$, when I only know three points $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and angle bisectors of the angles $A X_1 B$, $A X_2 B$ and $A X_3 B$. How do I do this geometrically?

[image: task]

.

If I used only two points – $X_1$ and $X_2$ – and their respective lines, I'm able to find a point $B'$ for every $A'$, so that it fulfils the condition. This means it has infinite solutions.

[image: solution for 2 points]

.

For the two points the solution was pretty easy – I just needed draw the line $AX_1$ and then another one that is axially symmetric to it, then repeat for $X_2$. $B$ is at the intersection of the two axially symmetric lines.

However this approach isn't of much use when I use all the three points, as the lines usually don't meet at a single point.

[image: invalid solution for 3 points]

.

There's always one point A' such that the three lines *do meet* in one point. This is *the* solution, however I wasn't able to find it otherwise than moving it here and there using trial and error.

Comment: There isn't a single solution to your problem: trying with GeoGebra one can find several different couples of points $A$ and $B$.

Comment: There is a whole cubic curve of possible positions for $A$. If I find the time I can provide some instructions on how to find its formula, heavily based on projective geometry, complex numbers and stuff like that. Interested?

Comment: Take the lines $l_1, \, l_2, \, l_3$ passing through the points $X_1, \, X_2, \, X_3$ respectively and perpendicular to the respective angle bisectors. Then if the three intersection points $$Q_1 = l_1 \cap X_2X_3, \,\, Q_2 = l_2 \cap X_3X_1, \,\, Q_3 = l_3 \cap X_1X_2$$ are collinear (lie on the same line), there exists an ellipse (well, in general a conic curve) that passes through the points $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and is tangent to the lines $l_1, \, l_2, \, l_3$. Then, its seems to me, the two foci of the ellipse are exactly the points $A$ and $B$ that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In projective geometry and using homogeneous coordinates, you can express an angular bisector like this:

$$(A,Y_1;I,J)_{X_1} = (Y_1,B;I,J)_{X_1}$$

The parentheses denote cross ratios. $X_1$ is the point from which ous the cross ratio is seen; you might also consider this as the cross ratio of the lines from the given points to $X_1$. $Y_1$ is any other point on the given bisector; it might be a point at indfinity describing the direction. $I$ and $J$ are the ideal circle points with homogeneous coordinates $I=(1:i:0)$ and $J=(1:-i:0)$. The whole cross ratio is proportional to the exponent of the angle, via [Laguerre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_formula). Expanding the above and using square brackets for determinants, you get

$$[A,I,X_1][Y_1,J,X_1][Y_1,J,X_1][B,I,X_1]=[A,J,X_1][Y_1,I,X_1][Y_1,I,X_1][B,J,X_1]$$

From this you can conclude that $B$ lies on the line

$$[A,I,X_1][Y_1,J,X_1][Y_1,J,X_1](I\times X_1)-[A,J,X_1][Y_1,I,X_1][Y_1,I,X_1](J\times X_1)$$

which is just a complicated way to express what you get by reflecting the line $AX_1$ in the line $X_1Y_1$. If you want to, you can get rid of complex coordinates at this point, since they can be collected into a single common factor which may be discarded for homogeneous coordinates.

You can do the same computation (or merely adapt the result) for the other two pairs $(X_2,Y_2)$ and $(X_3,Y_3)$ and obtain two more lines. These three lines will be concurrent (and $B$ their point of intersection) iff their determinant is zero. So at this point you have a single equation in $A$ which is zero iff $A$ leads to a valid $B$. The point $A$ occurs of degree $3$ in this equation, so $A$ has to lie on a given cubic curve, its position determined by the $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Comment: Cool! There's a lot of fancy math, so it'll take me some time to actually understand it. However I've got two sub-questions: 1) If I added $X_4$, (or any number of points) would there be a single solution? 2) Are you aware of any geometric construction that would yield the cubic curve (as a locus)?

Comment: @m93a 1) Experiments suggest that for input in general position you'd get a single real solution which is unique up to swapping $A$ with $B$. You'd also get a pair of complex conjugate solutions. And depending on how you compute it you might get 3 “solutions” where $B$ is the null vector, because the lines used to compute it have become identical. 2) I'm not aware of any such construction, except that it's possible to translate *any* arithmetic transformation into geometry, so you could express my computation as a *huge* construction *in theory*.